# Annotation to default value

Tags: java, annotations

I have a visibility problem in projects, once my implementation is not visible as my interface. **The visibility problem can not be solved.**

I thought of a solution:

I wrote a note

```
@Target (ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention (RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Register {
}
```

I use it in classes

```
@Register
public class ClientAlteracaoObserver implements Complement <ClientGestaoValue>, IClienteAlteracaoObserver {
}
```

I create an engine at project initialization that records in a container the implementations and interfaces

```
public class Injection implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed( ServletContextEvent arg0 ) {

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized( ServletContextEvent arg0 ) {
        System.out.println( "Agora as coisas vão ficar boas!!!!" );
        Container container = Container.getInstance();
        ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider( true );
        scanner.addIncludeFilter( new AnnotationTypeFilter( Register.class ) );
        Set< BeanDefinition > registers = scanner.findCandidateComponents( "br.com.syonet" );

        for ( BeanDefinition bd : registers ) {
            try {
                Class< ? > clazz = Class.forName( bd.getBeanClassName() );
                List< Class< ? > > interfaces = Arrays.asList( clazz.getInterfaces() );
                for ( Class< ? > contract : interfaces ) {
                    container.register( contract, clazz );
                }
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println( "GG garotão!" );

    }
}
```

my container

```
public class Container {
    private static final Container instance = new Container();
    private final HashMap< String, Object> intances = new HashMap<>();

    private Container() { }

    public static Container getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void register( Class<?> contract, Class<?> contractImpl ) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        this.intances.put( contract.getName(), contractImpl.newInstance() );
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T get( Class<T> interfac ) {
        return ( T ) this.intances.get( interfac.getName() );
    }

    public static <T> T load( Class<T> interfac ) {
        return ( T ) instance.get( interfac );
    }

}
```

And finally I use this way:

```
class Test {
    private IClienteAlteracaoObserver observer = Container.load(IClienteAlteracaoObserver.class);
}
```

But I would like to create the annotation @Inject to do the work of `Container.load(IClienteAlteracaoObserver.class)`;

```
class Test {
    private @Inject IClienteAlteracaoObserver observer;
}
```

Comment: ... and your question is?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with creating annotation, but if you put `default "example"` after `field`?

Comment: You CAN do this with annotations. But this take some work. Or... more like a lot of work. You would need to write an annotation processor. I would recommend to use a `public static final String DEFAULT_FIELD_VALUE = ...-,` and use this in the default (i.e. parameterless) constructor. Alternatively, you can write a [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: Why don't you set the variable value in the class constructor?

Comment: @StatelessDev I'm creating something to automatically inject components, similar to `javax.inject` and `javax.ws.rs.core.Context`

Comment: @Turing85 Annotation processors can't modify existing code. An annotation processor would have to generate a factory of some kind, in a new and separate class.

Comment: @Radiodef As long as you restrict yourself to the documented Compiler API, this is true. But there are possbilities to modify code at compile-time. This is how [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) generates getters and setters.

Comment: @Turing85 Good luck reading the Javac source code to figure out how that works.

Comment: @Radiodef I do not intend to :) I just said it is possible.

Comment: I updated the description, to avoid confusion...

Comment: What you need is dependence injection. You can use spring framework.

Answer (score 0):

While what you want is possible, I would not recommend it. Annotations are primarily meta-information, mostly processed at compile-time. For this, one writes an annotation processor, which must be passed to the compiler so it can process the annotations. Baeldung has a [nice tutorial on annotation processing](http://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder) in which a simple builder is created through an annotation processor.

I propose an alternative in form of a static final variable:

```
public Class Test {
    public static final String DEFAULT_FIELD_VALUE = "example";
    private String field; // to ensure encapsulation, all attributes should be private

    public Test() {
        this(DEFAULT_FIELD_VALUE);
    }

    public Test(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return this.field;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(new Test().getField().equals("example"));
    }
}
```

([Ideone live demo](https://ideone.com/AEVx4e))

You can couple this approach with a `static`-block to make the configuration more flexible, by e.g. reading the default values from system variables or a config file.

If your objects start to become more complex, you can look at the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) for a more flexible solution.

A remark on your code: Due to data encapsulation, you do not want your class attributes accessible directly from the outside. Thus you should not set them `public`. Instead, write [mutator methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method#Java_example).